# SharePoint 2013 permissions popup

Tags: 2013, permissions, popup

Is there any way for when clicking on a link with restricted permissions to display a popup advising restricted access / "You do not have permissions" message rather than going to the system page that displays the message about not having rights to access? Thus keeping the user on the current page with the link. Obviously if they do have access, it will direct them to the linked page.

Thanks.